# loop concatenation using .concat without using just loop

Tags: java

I was wondering if there's a way to do use `String::concat` with loops, instead of using `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`.

I tried it like this, but it doesn't work. Could someone help fix up the problem? or give me suggestions so I try it myself?

```
    public class multiConcat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        String finish = "";
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String state = reader.next();
        System.out.println("Number of Concatenation: ");
        num = reader.nextInt();
        finish = state.concat(state);

            for (int i = 0; i == num; i++) {
              finish.concat(state);
            }

        System.out.println(finish);

    }
}
```

I thought it would be sthe ame idea as `x = x + 1`, i.e. constantly overwriting the value...

Thank you

you mean as this?

```
        for (int i = 0; i == num; i++) {
            finish = finish.concat(state);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting? Also, the first phrase is somewhat confuse, consider making it clearer.

Comment: I'm not getting any compiling errors. What im trying to do is if I enter "hi" for my word and i wanted to concat my world 4 times, so the result of this would be like "hihihihi" sorry for bad grammer

Comment: concat doesn't modify the string. use `finish = finish.concat(state);`. and remove this line `finish = state.concat(state);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few Changes.

1.) looping was not correct.

should be as below, if `num > 1` then concatenate in loop.

```
 if (num > 1) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++) {
                finish = finish.concat(state);
            }
        } else {
            finish = finish.concat(state);
        }
```

2.) `finish.concat(state)` returns a new String, so you have to assign in to the finish variable

```
finish = finish.concat(state); // **remember Strings are immutable**
```

Complete program

```
public class multiConcat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        String finish = "";
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String state = reader.next();
        System.out.println("Number of Concatenation: ");
        num = reader.nextInt();

        if (num > 1) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++) {
                finish = finish.concat(state);
            }
        } else {
            finish = finish.concat(state);
        }

        System.out.println(finish);

    }
}
```

**output**

```
Type a word: 
ankur
Number of Concatenation: 
2
ankurankur


Type a word: 
ankur
Number of Concatenation: 
1
ankur

Type a word: 
ankur
Number of Concatenation: 
3
ankurankurankur
```

Comment: ignore the if statement sorry... i posted the wrong code.. I was trying something on my own

Comment: I was trying to make it so If the person wants it concatenated less than twice It will just output the word

Comment: @JasonKim ok, that you can put a filter for `<2`, those things you can tweek i hope.

Comment: @JasonKim please upvote/accept the answer if it solves your purpose

Comment: I have couple more question

Comment: What is this equation... called x = x + 1?

Answer (score 2):

`finish.concat(state)` returns a new String, so you have to assign in to the `finish` variable in order for the reference to the new String to be kept :

`finish = finish.concat(state);`

You already do it prior to the loop, but inside the loop you are not doing anything with the return value of `concat`, and therefore the loop changes nothing.

Comment: @JasonKim you didn't fix the problem in the for loop, which I meantioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

`String is immutable` so you have to store returned value.

```
String finish = new String();
finish = finish.concat("Any Value");
```

Using `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` you can do this way

```
StringBuilder finish = new StringBuilder();
finish.append(state);

StringBuffer finish = new StringBuffer();
finish.append(state);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try using Stringbuilder and Stringbuffer next time :D

Comment: No problem. But 1 advice, if you are changing string value then it is better to use StringBuilder or Stringbuffer. Because everytime concat is called new memory is allocated for that string, as String is immutable.